# Power Point viewer asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, powerpoint

I want powerpoint viwer in asp.net mvc application. It should work on all platform .I should be open source . I just need powerpoint viewer.
Please tell me possible solutions 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view a PowerPoint in an ASP.NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461620/how-can-i-view-a-powerpoint-in-an-asp-net-application)

Comment: there aren't any free ones. Just Google "asp.net powerpoint viewer control"

Answer (score 1):

I found the [Office Viewer Component](http://www.ocxt.com/). Technically speaking this is an ActiveX control which is somehow capable of hosting MS Office documents. Using this component I successfully embedded PowerPoint presentation player into our prototype application by placing an instance of Office Viewer onto the main form. The C# code for opening a presentation and switching to slide show mode looked like this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

private AxOfficeViewer.AxOfficeViewer axOfficeViewer1;
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation _presentation;

public void OpenDocument(string fileName)
{
    axOfficeViewer1.Visible = false;

    axOfficeViewer1.Open(fileName);
    axOfficeViewer1.Visible = true;
    axOfficeViewer1.SlideShowPlay(false, false, false, false);

    _presentation =
        axOfficeViewer1.ActiveDocument as Presentation;
}
```

You could read more about this on [CodeProject - Embedding PowerPoint presentation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118676/Embedding-PowerPoint-presentation-player-into-a-WP)

Comment: It should be free and it should work on mobile also . Will it?

Comment: Yes it is free but works on mobile or not .. you need to check

Comment: First it is not free Second it only support window platform .